# IO errors using memory mapped files in Java

Tags: java, exception, memory-mapped-files

I'm using memory mapped files in some Java code to quickly write to a 2G file. I'm mapping the entire file into memory. The issue I have with my solution is that if the file I'm writing to mysteriously disappears or the disk has some type of error, those errors aren't getting bubbled up to the Java code.

In fact, from the Java code, it looks as though my write completed successfully. Here's the unit test I created to simulate this type of failure:

```
File twoGigFile = new File("big.bin");
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(twoGigFile, "rw");
raf.setLength(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
raf.seek(30000); // Totally arbitrary
raf.writeInt(42);
raf.writeInt(42);

MappedByteBuffer buf = raf.getChannel().map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
buf.force();
buf.position(1000000); // Totally arbitrary
buf.putInt(0);

assertTrue(twoGigFile.delete());

buf.putInt(0);
raf.close();
```

This code runs without any errors at all. This is quite an issue for me. I can't seem to find anything out there that speaks about this type of issue. Does anyone know how to get memory mapped files to correctly throw exceptions? Or if there is another way to ensure that the data is actually written to the file?

I'm trying to avoid using a RandomAccessFile because they are much slower than memory mapped files. However, there might not be any other option.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. To quote the JavaDoc:

> All or part of a mapped byte buffer may become inaccessible at any time [...] An attempt to access an inaccessible region of a mapped byte buffer will not change the buffer's content and will cause an unspecified exception to be thrown either at the time of the access or at some later time.

And here's why: when you use a mapped buffer, you are changing *memory*, not the file. The fact that the memory happens to be backed by the file is irrelevant until the OS attempts to write the buffered blocks to disk, which is something that is managed entirely by the OS (ie, your application will not know it's happening).

If you expect the file to disappear underneath you, then you'll have to use an alternate mechanism to see if this happens. One possibility is to occasionally touch the file using a `RandomAccessFile`, and catch the error that it will throw. Depending on your OS, even this may not be sufficient: on Linux, for example, a file exists for those programs that have an open handle to it, even if it has been deleted externally.

Comment: If you notice though, I am telling the memory mapped buffer to force the changes to be written to disk. That should create exceptions early rather than waiting for pages to be written from memory to disk by the OS.

Comment: One other thing, the delete I have in my test is merely an easily testable case. I don't expect that to happen ever. It is much more likely that the disk could be corrupt, crash, get unmounted, etc. Those cases are much more difficult to test though.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that `force()` will throw exceptions, it isn't declared to do so. Under the covers (at least on POSIX), it calls [msync](http://linux.die.net/man/2/msync), which only reports invocation errors.

Comment: You might also ask yourself how you're going to deal with the case where changes get written to the drive's front-end cache, but never make it to the platter. Or the case where everything gets written, and the disk immediately fails. But if those cases are important to you, a simple memory-mapped file will not be sufficient.

Comment: parisfal - the contract of MappedByteBuffer is that it can throw unknown and undocumented exceptions at any point. I figured that force would do the trick because the contract of that method is to force a write to disk, which apparently it doesn't do at all, otherwise it would report an error.

Comment: @Brian - I don't know what to say. You seem to be making an enormous number of completely unwarranted assumptions about how mapped files work. For that matter, about how filesystems work. I suggest that you spend some time learning those topics for your platform of choice. I've given you a pointer in an earlier comment. Good luck.

Comment: Parsifal - I have a firm understanding of the way everything works. The point here is that the OS paging from RAM to disk will fail at some point but those errors are not passed back up to Java in any form. What is really needed is a listener of sorts or a way to force a page write. The documentation of the force method looks to provide the correct handling, but in reality, calling that method actually does nothing. Furthermore, memory mapped files do produce errors at the OS level but java never sees them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17265/discussion-between-brian-pontarelli-and-parsifal)